# Can we create and use custom log file in install4j?

Tags: logging, runtime, size, customization, install4j

Is there is any way to crate and show custom log file in install4j other than the file which gets created in tmp folder on linux platform?
Or can we create custom log file through java code using run script actions?

How can we calculate required size for installation because my file structure has tar.gz files which get extracted at run time so size gets increased?

Comment: As per the rules of Stackoverflow, please ask separate questions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the JAR files of a logging framework to the custom code (Installer->Custom code & Resources) and call its methods in "Run script" actions or any script properties.